# Dummy variables and preProcess

Tags: r, r-caret

I have a data frame with some dummy variables that I want to use as training set for `glmnet`.

Since I'm using `glmnet` I want to center and scale the features using the `preProcess` option in the caret `train` function. I don't want that this transformation is applied also to the dummy variables.

Is there a way to prevent the transformation of these variables?

Comment: Good question. We are having same issue in my group and trying to avoid hacky solutions. I will keep you updated in case something comes out.

Comment: AFAIK this is not addressed in `caret::train` and `caret::trainControl` yet, and the current status is the same as in [this question from 2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023423/how-to-preprocess-features-when-some-of-them-are-factors). So using a "hacky" workaround will eventually be the way to go at the moment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not (currently) a way to do this besides writing a [custom model](http://topepo.github.io/caret/custom_models.html) to do so (see the example with PLS and RF near the end).

I'm working on a method to specify which variables get which pre-processing method. However, with dummy variables, this is tough since you might need to specific the names of a lot of predictors whose columns are not in the current dat set. The idea is to be able to use wildcards (e.g. `Species*` to capture `Speciesversicolor` and `Speciesvirginica`) but the code isn't quite there yet.

Max

Comment: Could you please let me know if there already is a way to do so? If not, I would appreciate it if you could fix the problem with the link to custom model.